# Show files in browser that are not in web directory and not linkable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, laravel-5.8, document-view

We are using Laravel v.5.8 and have our public files in a directory like...

```
/www/public/pubfiles/myfile.php
```

I can link to these with no problem. We also have an upload script that by design puts the files in...

```
/uploads/nonlinkablefile
```

And then stores the path and a filename, etc. in a db. When someone clicks a link to retrieve these files, a script gets the file and returns it as a download.

The files in the second option are stored this way so they cannot be linked to or shared. We are able to check a users permission on pages or directly on a file to see if they should be able to download.

What I'm wondering now is, if we can do those checks, and then somehow display the files (PDFs moslty) in a new tab in the browser vs. forcing a download.

Since there isn't a web-enable path to the file, I'm not finding a way to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the `file()` function, instead of a download ask the browser to open the file, i.e.:

```
return response()->file('/uploads/nonlinkablefile.pdf');
```

You can find more info in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads).

Obviously the path in which the files are stored should be accessible by the webserver, but the file does not need to be under the `public` or `DocumentRoot` directory.